# Is it possible to display a NSWindow on a CALayer?

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, calayer, nswindow

I'm provided with a `CALayer*` and would like to know if it's possible to dynamically create a `NSWindow` and show it on the layer?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm provided with a CALayer* and would like to know if it's possible to dynamically create a NSWindow …

Yes.

> … and show it on the layer?

Nope.

You can make a layer that knows about the window or its content view and, when [told to draw](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/drawInContext%3a), tells the window's content view to [draw](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/drawRect%3a), or you could [take a screenshot of the window](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CGWindow_Reference/Reference/Functions.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGWindowListCreateImage) and set it as [the layer's contents](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/contents). But you can't put a window into a layer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Peter, i'll give it a try this evening.